# Static files not updating on prod

Tags: django, nginx, production-environment

I am new to production stuff. I deployed my first Django app on digital ocean . It's working.

The code is updating fine but the problem is with the static files which are serving through nginx.

I updated the static files and restart nginx and gunicorn but they are not present in my prod website.

I checked with chrome dev tools and it's serving old static files.

I checked these changes are present in the prod repo but somehow nginx don't seem to be using the latest static files . The steps I took

```
      Run collectstatic command
      Restart the nginx
      Restart the gunicorn
```

The nginx config for static files

```
   location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
    root /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/hkc_project;
}
```

This is static settings:

```
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'hkc/static')
    ]
```

Is there anything else I have to do for this to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show how your STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT are defined?

Comment: @JuanMiGabarron yes sure.

Comment: Have you done `python manage.py collectstatic` ? tried to clear cache with dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know nginx, the best way to serve the static files with it is:

```
    location /static {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/hkc_project;    
    }
```

`alias` is the proper method to serve entire directories.

`autoindex` processes requests ending with the slash character (‘/’) and produces a directory listing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to be a cache issue on browser. After refreshing it multiple time solved the issue. But I will sure look into this method you mentioned.